# Show that $\mathbb R_1^2$ and $\mathbb R_{\infty}^2$ are isometric

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

How can I show that $\mathbb R_1^2$ and $\mathbb R_{\infty}^2$ are isometric.

I know that it suffices to find a bijective map $T:\mathbb R_1^2 \to \mathbb R_{\infty}^2$ such that $\|T(x_1,y_1)-T(x_2,y_2)\|_{\infty}=\|(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\|_1$ but I have a hard time in constructing such $T$.

Can someone be of help, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to visualize their unit balls. Then you might get an idea for the transformation.

Comment: @daw the respective unit balls are Kite and square. How can I find the transformation. Please I an new in this.

Comment: @STaura They are both square, just oriented differently. Try defining a linear map from $\Bbb{R}^2_1$ to $\Bbb{R}^2_\infty$ that maps the corners of one square to the other.